# Proxy Server in Django or Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, iframe, proxy

I am tryigng to build a webpage in Django, which contains a mini "browser", an input bar for inputing link and an iframe for displaying the webpage, like this website (http://free-proxyserver.com/). But a lot of pages cannot be load in the iframe due to different reasons, like google, stackoverflow etc. So I want to build a proxy server on my server. For links like "https://www.google.com", I will set the iframe source to "http://mywebsite.com/proxy?url=https://www.google.com", and there will be a view function for "/proxy".

If I just request this page and send the response back, the web user will not be able to get any .js or .css files. Is there an easy way to fix this?

I have tried to search open source proxy server for django, projects like "[Django Http Proxy](http://django-http-proxy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)" can only be proxy for one certain website, but I want it to be a proxy for all possible websites.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the [Django Http Proxy documentation](http://django-http-proxy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation.html), you will find that:

> Older versions of Django HTTP Proxy only supported a single proxy per
>   Django project, which had to be configured using a Django setting:
>
> ```
> PROXY_BASE_URL = 'http://www.python.org/
> ```
>
> Naturally, you can easily replicate this behavior using the new class-based view syntax:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
> from httpproxy.views import HttpProxy
> urlpatterns += patterns('',
>     (r'^proxy/(?P<url>.*)$',
>         HttpProxy.as_view(base_url=settings.PROXY_BASE_URL)), )
> ```

So, I think you can easily modify base_url and read it from the client input.